Usage of 面で in this sentence

過分にプライベートなことを香織に抜け抜けと話すのはデリカシー面でどうだろうか。客商売を長くしている身として気になった

The character is a host/bartender/etc who work in the 客商売. He's about to talk to his client about his private life, however as far I gather, he's not sure he should.
What I don't understand is, what is this usage of 面で? I take he may be saying "It may be a delicate issue"?

X(の)面【めん】(で) means "(in) the aspect of X", "(on) the X front" or "(in) terms of X". This 面 is read as めん and means "surface", "side" or "aspect". デリカシー面でどうだろうか means "Is it okay, from a sensitivity standpoint?"
Similar examples:

防衛面で不安が残っている
There are remaining concerns in terms of defense
精神面でのケア
care on the mental side (as opposed to the physical side)
財政面を負担する
to handle the financial side (of the matter)

